Django: url transition doesn't work, how to fix it?
Good afternoon!
I encountered this bug: when clicking on a link, the url changes, but the transition to another page doesn't work.
To be more precise:
There is a page that displays information about an article (test is the slug of the article): http://127.0.0.1:8001/articles/article/test/
url to go to the update page: http://127.0.0.1:8001/articles/article/test/update/
Composition of the urls.py file:
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='articles_catalog'),
    path('article/<slug:slug>/<str:author>/', views.details, name='comment_creation'),
    path('article/<slug:slug>/update/', views.update_article, name='update_article'),
    path('article/<slug:slug>/', views.details, name='details'),
    path('new_article/', views.new_article, name='new_article')
]

Link to go to:
<a
      href="{% url 'articles:update_article' slug=article.slug %}"
      id="update_article"
      target="_self"
      rel="noreferrer noopener"
      class="thq-button-filled thq-button-animated"
      >
           UPDATE
</a>

The view itself:
@login_required()
def update_article(request, slug):
    print('OK1')
    article = Article.objects.get(slug=slug)
    tags = Tag.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('POST')
    else:
        form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
        return render(request, 'articles/create-update.html', {'form': form, 'tags': tags})

As a result, when I click on the link, the url in the address bar changes, but the page itself - remains the same.
Please advise me what I might have missed.

The route article/<slug:slug>/<str:author>/ matches before article/<slug:slug>/update/ does, because "update" is a valid author string. Change the order of these URLs so the update route comes first.
This basically also means "update" is a special value and you can never have an author called "update", which you should ensure somehow.
